# Java RegEx not working as expected

Tags: java, regex

Wondering if someone can tell me why this regular expression doesn't work.

Expression -> `^[A-Za-z0-9$&!#-_?:;\"']+$`

The problem is, it's matching against characters not in the set. For example, the word `match` properly matches and the word `match~` does not, but `match@` and `match!` incorrectly match.

I'm using java to match it, and the matching should be fairly straight forward with the code below:

```
        RE re = new RE(expression);
        return re.match(value);
```

I know it's probably something ridiculously simple that I'm missing, but if anyone has any thoughts on it, I'd greatly appreciate it!

Comment: According to your expression `match!` is an acceptable value.

Comment: This begs the question 'Why would `m`atch pass the test?' According to you `m` is not in the character class. You seem to understand the syntax of classes. You even seem to know about assertions, quantifiers and such..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the hyphen `-` in your character set. Your are accepting characters from # to _.

Change it to `^[-A-Za-z0-9$&!#_?:;\"']+$` or escape `-`.

Comment: Bruno, this was exactly the problem. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect its `#-_` that is acting up. Escape the `-` and see if that helps.

New expression would be `^[A-Za-z0-9$&!#\-_?:;\"']+$`